# Add a bottom menu for RecyclerView item

Tags: android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, android-viewholder, navigationview

I have a recyclerview that will have an option button to the right, and I want to achieve something like the animation below:

[image: desired result]

I'm using [this](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-menu-and-navigation-c4f069e579ec) as my reference but I have some disconnects.

First I want to know if I can even do this because every thing I find on adding a menu to a recyclerview is adding a basic menu pop up, which is not what I want.

I also have some disconnect on accessing the menu from the viewholder, I can access it from my fragment but I'd think I'd need to call it from the viewholder so I have what row clicked to fire up the menu.

If I'm overthinking the implementation and there's a simpler approach, I'm open to hearing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if I am understanding what you want, but if it is to have a button that exist in the row items of the recyclerview to pop up a drawer from the bottom of the screen whenever the button is clicked, then you should just use a normal drawer setup ([Navigation Drawer](https://material.io/design/components/navigation-drawer.html#bottom-drawer), [Create a navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#java)) for the activity and have an `OnClickListener` added to the row buttons (which can be done in `onCreateViewHolder()` or the holder's constructor) that triggers the drawer to open by calling `openDrawer()`. Note to do the latter, you have to pass the navigation drawer (`DrawerLayout`) into the adapter via the adaptors constructor (which means your adapter needs something to store the `DrawerLayout` in).

So

```
public class CustomAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>{
        private Context mContext;
        private int mLayoutResourceId;
        private ArrayList<Item> items;
        private DrawerLayout drawer;

        public CustomAdaptor (Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Item> itemArray, DrawerLayout drawer) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mLayoutResourceId = resource;
            this.items = itemArray;
            this.drawer = drawer;
        }

        public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
           final CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);

           holder.mbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   //Check if drawer is null and if not then call
                   drawer.drawerOpen();
                }
           });
           return holder;
        }
}
```

where `mButton` is the button in the holder/row. Note I havent tested this so there might be somethings im forgetting.